# usage of "sort out"

Tags: word-usage

[From the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sort%20out)

> sort out: to understand or find (something, such as a reason or a solution) by thinking

> I'm trying to **sort out a way** to do it.

> sort out: to find an answer or solution for (something)

> He's still trying to **sort out his problems**.

> sort out: to solve the problems of (someone)

> They're still trying to **sort their son out**.

I understand the all three meanings listed, I don't see the difference in usage with corresponding meanings. Could someone help me on this?

Comment: The differences aren't really significant. If you understand the three cited example usages, that's good enough. What difference does it make to you that *some* people see a "difference" between, say, sorting out ***an actual problem*** and sorting out ***a person with a problem***?

Comment: They are all informal, and, I suspect, mostly used in British English.

Comment: The first two are used in AmE and BrE, the third one is not generally used in AmE but would be understood without any problem. Often, in the everyday  BrE usage of sort out (Please sort this out), in AmE, it would be: Please take care of this. [problem]